# Conditional Rendering and Const Setup of global variables-typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working on a react typescript project and have a global utility that has a constructor and fills itself a database-but only after the user clicks a button. My problem is that the display modal to display the information is still rendering and so I get a type error cannot read undefined. How can I stop the component from running through getters into const vars and only run the const when I ask it to render?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fallback and pass in conditionally.
I.e

`{modal ? modal : fallback}`

Don't know if this clarifies anything, there's no code to see so I don't basically know what you're working with but this concept should suffice.